# How to create table with title in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I want to create a Table in React native like the below image

### TABLE PICTURE

[image]

i have two JSON data

tableTitle.json

```
var tableTitle = [ 
    { id: '11', last_nom: 'Cars'},
    { id: '12', last_nom: 'Phones'}
];
```

tableInfo.json

```
var tableInfo = [ 
    { id: '1', parent_id: '11', name: 'toyota', model:'camry', year:'2020', country:'japan'},
    { id: '2', parent_id: '11', name: 'huyndai', model:'accent', year:'2018', country:'s.korea'},
    { id: '3', parent_id: '11', name: 'tesla', model:'s30', year:'2022', country:'usa'},
    { id: '4', parent_id: '12', name: 'iphone', model:'14 pro', year:'2020', country:'usa'},
    { id: '5', parent_id: '12', name: 'samsung', model:'ss22', year:'2018', country:'s.korea'},
    { id: '6', parent_id: '12', name: 'pixel', model:'4', year:'2022', country:'usa'},
];
```

Get table title

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const config = {
      method:'get',
      url: `http://URL.COM/${id}`,
      headers: {  }
    }
    axios(config)
     .then(function(response){
      let info = response.data
      let newArray = info.map((list)=>{
        return {id: list.id, name: list.name}
      })
        setTitle(newArray)
        // console.log(newArray)
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
     })
})
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: How can i message you? to explain

Comment: It would be helpful for people trying to answer your question if you put additional information in the question itself-- what code you have written to display the table, and how the output of that code is different than what you want.  That way, you're asking them to help solve a specific problem, instead of a more general request to "write some code for me."

Comment: So, for example: "Here's the code I tried, and it gave me this error when I ran it."  or, "Here's my code.  The output looks like this, but I want it to look like this other thing instead."